# Изменить php код wp_nav_menu для изменения html разметки

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

Имеется меню с выпадающим списком у некоторых пунктов. Для отображения меню я использую [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#source).

По имеющемуся дизайну необходимо изменить структуру `html`. Изменить тэг `a` на тэг `span` у пунктов меню с вложенным списком. Т.е. если у пункта меню есть вложенный список, он не должен быть ссылкой. В итоге нужно получить такую структуру меню:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Parent item</a></li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
     <span>Parent item</span>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="">text1</a></li>
       <li><a href="">text2</a></li>                             
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Parent item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Как можно изменить код `wp_nav_menu` чтобы получить такую структуру меню?

**UPD**

Есть такое [решение](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199602/replace-anchor-tag-with-span-tag). Но этот код меняет всю разметку, нет проверки на наличие вложенных списков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделала так:

```
class menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
    $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

    $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';


    $item_output = $args->before;
    if ( $args->walker->has_children && 0 === $depth ) {
        $item_output .= '<span>';
    } else {
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
    }

    $item_output .= $args->link_before .apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
    $item_output .= ( $args->walker->has_children && 0 === $depth ) ? ' </span>' : '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;
    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно добавить фильтр - add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'my_function') в функцию темы (в файл function.php).

```
function replace_tag($block_menu) {

    // Выбираем все <a>...</a>
    preg_match_all('|<a(.*?)</a>|is', $block_menu,  $out_dat);

    // Проходим в цикле по всем выбранным тегам '<a>' 
    foreach( $out_dat[0] AS $out_d)
    {
        // если встретили класс "dropdown-toggle" то делаем 2 действия: получаем анкор и заменяем строку "<a .... </a>"  на нашу 
        if(strpos($out_d, 'dropdown-toggle'))
        {
            preg_match('|>(.*?)<|is', $out_d,  $ancor);
            $block_menu = str_replace($out_d, '<span>' . $ancor[1] . '</span>',  $block_menu);
        }
    }

    return $block_menu;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','replace_tag');
```

Comment: спасибо за код. но у меня он не работает. пробовала немножко изменять, в т.ч. я изменила `'dropdown-toggle'` на `'menu-item-has-children'` у элемента списка `li`.

Comment: еще нашла такое решение https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199602/replace-anchor-tag-with-span-tag. но тут меняется вся разметка, нет проверки на наличие вложенных списков

Answer (score 0):

А обязательно именно менять его? Добавление кода в `functions.php` это так сказать костыль, лишняя обработка сервером. Есть более лаконичный способ на чистом `css` : просто добавляете к выводимым линкам класс, а потом

```
.inactiveLink {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Тег остался, но никаких событий при нажатии на ссылку с классом не происходит, и не прийдется пилить фильтры(которых в более-менее крупном проекте и так хватает).

Comment: спасибо за вариант со стилями. но необходимо именно изменить разметку (тэг)